# Do I need a resident permit to study in Germany as an EU Citizen?

Tags: germany, eu-citizens, resident-permit, italian-citizens

I am an EU citizen (Italian if that matters) planning to move to Germany to study at a university, that is for one year long period.

Do I need to apply for a residence permit or some related document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need a resident permit as an EU national. However you need to register with the local police (Bürgeramt) within 7 days of finding permanent residence.

[See here for more information.](http://germany.angloinfo.com/moving/residency/eu-citizens/)